# Yii error in internal pages

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a problem with the internal tabs that cannot be found but the routing is correct I do not know why this error is due to the fact that only the view of the home works, I would appreciate any support

Add a snippet of code when loading the modules

```
 'admin' => array(
        'class' => 'core.modules.admin.AdminModule',
        // Este parametro lo reciben todos los módulos
        // y es para ocultar el menu lateral en el cms
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false,
    ),
    'payu'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.payu.PayuModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
    'Home'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.Home.HomeModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
     'secciones'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.secciones.SeccionesModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
    'Noticias'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.Noticias.NoticiasModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
    'Galeria'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.Galeria.GaleriaModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
     'eventos'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.eventos.EventosModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
    'involucrate'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.involucrate.InvolucrateModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
    'conocenos'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.conocenos.ConocenosModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
     'documentos'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.documentos.DocumentosModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
    'contactenos'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.contactenos.ContactenosModule',
        // 'showMenuFromAdmin'=>false, // If you want hide your module on CMS left menu
     ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I found the error the routes were correctly but the htacces was wrongly configured here I leave it in case it happens the same

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~lindemipagina/
# This is for OAuth2 Implementation of "Authorization" parameter
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

# This is for uploader pluging
# php_value post_max_size 100M
# php_value upload_max_filesize 100M

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```